# SPNEGO Authentication Failing

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, authentication

I have setup kerberos + OpenLDAP authentication for my Apache 2.4 CentOS 7 machine fine.  I'm now trying to setup SSO using Kerberos + OpenLDAP for Tomcat 7.  For this I've selected SPNEGO.  I believe I have all of the LDAP and Kerberos settings working as needed.

Now when browsing to the webapp that has SPNEGO Authentication enabled I'm getting a 401, this is because my user agent isn't sending a WWW-Negotation header.  I was expecting this as I haven't got to this point yet.

My question is specific to logging in.  In Apache 2.4 I have setup SSO and if no key is present it uses basic authentication and works perfectly, as expected it grants me a TGT after providing credentials and is valid for the entire session.

I'd like to have Tomcat 7 present me with a login prompt on fail such as the 401 error message I'm getting now.

Additionally, I've also setup AJP.  Just for testing, I thought I'd try to AJP from Apache to Tomcat with SSO enabled.  While watching my kerberos logs, it is infact authenticating when I view the webapp but am still presented with a 401.

tldr;
How can I make Tomcat 7 prompt for a username and password if needed?  And is there a way using AJP to stay authenticated from Apache to a webapp over the AJP tunnel?

The following is a snippet of my Tomcat 7 logs, please let me know what other information is needed.

```
Apr 28, 2016 12:58:08 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE: Security checking request GET /helloworld/
Apr 28, 2016 12:58:08 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase findSecurityConstraints
FINE:   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[all]' against GET /index.jsp --> true
Apr 28, 2016 12:58:08 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase findSecurityConstraints
FINE:   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[all]' against GET /index.jsp --> true
Apr 28, 2016 12:58:08 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
Apr 28, 2016 12:58:08 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase hasUserDataPermission
FINE:   User data constraint has no restrictions
Apr 28, 2016 12:58:08 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Calling authenticate()
Apr 28, 2016 12:58:08 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator authenticate
FINE: No authorization header sent by client
Apr 28, 2016 12:58:08 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Failed authenticate() test
```

Comment: for the second question, you can try with the `tomcatAuthentication` and `tomcatAuthorization` attributes (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html)

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have configured auth-method as SPNEGO in Tomcat web.xml and want it to fall back to BASIC when it doesn't receive  TGT from your user agent ?

Comment: Roshith, yes.  I'd like the user to be prompted to enter their credentials if not sent by their browser.